# Travis environment variable (Python)

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have set up "ENVIRONMENT" as an environment variable in the Travis console, but when Travis runs, it still can't access the variable in Python. Any idea?

```
  File "/home/travis/build/.../config/env.py", line 12, in set
    builtins.environment = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ENVIRONMENT'
```

Comment: not without more details. Linux? maybe you should `export` the value so children have access to them.

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt an answer, as it's the only reason I can think of.

on Linux/unix bash/ksh, doing:

```
ENVIRONMENT=somevalue
```

doesn't propagate the value to children processes. You have to `export` (in bash):

```
export ENVIRONMENT=somevalue
```